# text ouptut in form validation running out of the output message box

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a form that after submission it displays the result in a box, but when I enter too much information (text) in the text box (textarea) it runs out of the box in the output. The solution that I thought it would work, would be to modify the style of the id="output" at the bottom of page to width:450px, but that didn't work.... are there any other suggestions? [Here's the link to the form](http://www.sohotechnology.org/contact.html)

here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta content="computer repair, laptop repair, wireless installation, printer installation, printer repair, system administration, website design, web administration, logo design, web application development, computer repair miami fl, web design miami fl, system administration miami fl" name="keywords"> 
    <meta name="Computer Soloution for Small Business and Home Users, Miami, Florida" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Contact Us</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- font awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- font mfizz -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-mfizz/font-mfizz.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="icons/flaticon.css">


    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- custome css style sheet -->
    <link href="carosel_style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- google analytics code -->
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-61593038-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

        //form validation and submition
        function validateForm()
        {
            var fullName = document.forms['myForm']['name'].value;
            var emailAdd = document.forms['myForm']['email'].value;
            var subject = document.forms['myForm']['subject'].value;
            var message = document.forms['myForm']['message'].value;
            var outputMsg = "";

            var emailReg = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;

            //validating form fields
            if(fullName == null || fullName == "") {
                outputMsg += "Name field can not be empty!\n";
            }
            if(emailAdd == null || emailAdd == "") {
                outputMsg += "Email field can not be empty!\n";
            }
            //if email field not empty check for valid email add
            if(emailAdd != "" && !emailReg.test(emailAdd)) {
                outputMsg += "Enter a valid email address!\n";

            }
            if(message == null || message == "") {
                outputMsg += "Text field can not be empty!\n";
            }   
            if(outputMsg != "") {
                alert(outputMsg);
                return false;
            }   

            //sending data fields to php form
            var params = "name="+fullName+"&email="+emailAdd+"&subject="+subject+"&message="+message;

            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

                xmlhttp.open("POST", "contact.php", true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)

                {
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.send(params);

            //change the style of "ouput" id
            document.getElementById("output").style.border = "solid 1px #5A5A5A";
            document.getElementById("output").style.padding = "10px";
            document.getElementById("output").style.width = "450px";
        }       

    </script>
  </head>
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
  <body>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img id="main-logo" src="img/title_logo1.png">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="#"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://pctechtips.org">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="index.html#computer">Comuter Repair</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#system">System Administration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#webdesign">Website Design</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Carousel
    ================================================== -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
     <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/computer-keyboard-closeup-header.jpg" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>COMPUTER SOLUTIONS FOR HOME AND SMALL BUSINESS.</h1>
              <p>Professional IT Support for Home Office, and Small Bussiness. Computer Repair, Printer Repair, Network Suport, System Administration, and Web Design</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Get a Quote</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>      
    </div>

    <!-- /.carousel -->


    <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

    <div class="container marketing">
        <div class="hero-unit" style="padding:20px 100px">
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            <p>Please send us a description of your computer problems and a we will be in touch as soon as possible with a quote:</p>       
        </div>      
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="my-form">
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="myForm"  >
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Text:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="Text"></textarea>
              </div>    
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="validateForm()">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>    
            </div> 
        </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">

             <img id="google-img" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Miami+Downtown,Miami,FL&zoom=13&size=500x350&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7CMiami+Downtown,Miami,FL">
          </div>         
      </div><!-- /.row -->
      <div class="row">  <!-- output message rown -->           
            <div class="col-sm-6" >
                    <!-- display form result message here! -->
                    <p id="output" >
                    </p>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!--nothing goes here!-->
            </div>      
        </div>

      <!-- FOOTER -->
      <footer>            
        <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
        <p>&copy; 2015 Jorge L. Vazquez &middot;<a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
      </footer>
    </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The p element 'output' that has the content needs

```
#output{
 word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

`break-word` allows words to break and wrap to the next line

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here. On the box, you can try this for CSS:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

This will allow you to scroll right/left in the box rather than have it bleed out.

If you want to force it to wrap without scroll:

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
<p id="output" style="overflow: scroll; word-wrap:break-word;"></p>
```